# how to align selected dropdown value to the right

Tags: flutter

Playing with flutter and while this is not totally crucial to the MVP of my project it is like a thorn in my side. How can I align the selected value to the right so it is up against the icon in a DropdownButton. This is what I have so far.

```
      DropdownButton<String>(
        value: globals.things,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Raleway',
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(36, 96, 208, 1),
          height: 2),
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
          color: Colors.white,
          ),
        iconSize: 40,
        underline: Container(
          height: 2,
        ),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            globals.things = newValue;
            _response = _getStuff(mapToApiKey(globals.things));
          });
        },
        items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(
                value,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(54, 38, 83, 1)),
                ),
            );
          }).toList(),
      ),
```

[image]

## Edit after playing with this

It appears that with out any alignment flutter does want to align the selected value close to the dropdown button icon. The reason that I was having such a gap is some of my menu items are much longer than the 'one' they are something like 'one two three'. What it looks like is that flutter wants there to be enough room to fit the longest menu item aligned to right of the icon. By shortening my dropdown menu items I was able to get a more pleasant look.

Comment: Do you mean "right"? Because this is already in left!

Comment: :face_palm: lol yeah might have been working for a little to long on this yesterday. Wasnt thinking straight

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Comment: I did not find a solution, but did notice that the gap space was based off the longest list item. So in my case I was able to find a way to rephrase my longest list item and this made the list look better.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap `Text` widget in `DropdownMenuItem`'s child with a `container` and give it `alignment: Alignment.centerRight`. Like this:

```
items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six']
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Text(
                    value,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(54, 38, 83, 1)),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
```

**Nerd Stuff**

The Text widget's size default is to wrap its content. so adding alignment to it won't change anything really. The Container's size by default is also wrap content, but after adding the alignment, the size changes to fill its parent (in this case, the DropDownMenu). So with `alignment: Alignment.Somewhere` you can move the child freely.

**Edit**

If you want to align only the selected value to the right, change the alignment to this:
`alignment:value == globals.things ? Alignment.centerRight :Alignment.centerLeft,`

Comment: This suggestion does allow me to change the alignment of the child items in the drop down menu, but that is not what I am trying to do. Perhaps I was unclear. I am trying to align the value of the dropdown button widget.

Comment: By value,  do you mean the selected item? In my code all the items is to the right. Or, you want the value be to the right of the arrow icon?

Comment: I mean the selected vale, I will try this again, later. I have noticed sometimes the hot reload isnt the greatest and I should have uninstalled the app to really test. But ideally I would like only the selected item to be to the right, just so it is closer to the icon and there isnt such a gap. I actually like how the dropdown children are aligned to the left by default.

Comment: Editing my answer, I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for trying I found out why my app was behaving the way it was and updated my answers. I attempted your solution but found that this did not change the alignment of the selected item it just changed how the items in the drop down were aligned. And with your recent edit just made it so one item in the list was aligned differently than the others.